# Does local Hölder-continuity suffice to get an upper bound for Hausdorff dimension - or does it need to be global? ((Mistake in the literature?))

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, fractals, hausdorff-measure

It is a well-known fact that Brownian Motion is almost surely **locally** $\alpha$-Hölder continuous for $\alpha\in(0,1/2)$. This is sometimes used in conjunction with the following result concerning Hausdorff dimension -- when proving McKean's Theorem, for instance (that is, Proposition 2 strengthened to equality).

**Proposition 1.** Let $(M,d_1)$ and $(N,d_2)$ be two metric spaces, and $f:M\to N$ a (**globally**) $\gamma$-Hölder continuous function with $\gamma$-Hölder constant $L$. Then we have, for all $\alpha\geq0$, and for all subsets $A$ of $M$, that
\begin{equation*}
    \mathcal{H}^{\infty}_{\alpha/\gamma}(f(A))\leq L^{\alpha/\gamma}\cdot\mathcal{H}^{\infty}_{\alpha}(A)
\end{equation*}
In particular, we have that $\dim f(A)\leq\frac{1}{\gamma}\dim A$. $\Diamond$

Here, we denote by $\mathcal{H}^{\infty}_{\alpha}(A)$ the unlimited $\alpha$-Hausdorff content of $A$. One then uses Proposition 1, in some way, to show that

**Proposition 2.** Let $\{B(t):t\geq0\}$ be $d$-dimensional Brownian motion, and fix a subset $A$ of $[0,\infty)$. Then, almost surely,
$\dim B(A)\leq\min(2\dim A,d)$. $\Diamond$

since we already know that Brownian motion is almost surely **locally** $\alpha$-Hölder continuous. My question is: How can we bridge the gap from Hölder continuity in Proposition 1 to just **local** Hölder continuity?

All books I have taken a look at either ignore the distinction between the two -- or just remark that it is sufficient if $f$ is only locally Hölder continuous, without providing a proof. This is, for example, done in *[Brownian Motion (2010)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/brownian-motion/F639B9A8403BD465F896F3E18A9C3382)* by Peter Mörters and Yuval Peres, with Remark 4.15 on page 102 ([here](https://people.bath.ac.uk/maspm/book.pdf) is a publicly available pdf, provided by the University of Bath). It seems that the three Bachelor's thesis/essays [here](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Shah.pdf), [here](https://personal.lse.ac.uk/MERGONID/documents/BSc_Thesis.pdf) and [here](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/VIGRE/VIGRE2011/REUPapers/Hansen.pdf) have relied upon that remark without further justification. On the other hand, the books treating Hausdorff measure by [Falconer (2003)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2118797) and [Mattila (1995)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/geometry-of-sets-and-measures-in-euclidean-spaces/3E3DDE579ABAEEC863B8964D68DCC72F) only state results for globally Hölder continuous functions, and make no mention of strengthened versions for local Hölder continuity.

So far, I have tried the following to prove Proposition 1 for locally Hölder continuous functions, but haven't made much progress.

**Proposition 3.** If $(M,d_1)$ is a separable metric space, we can replace the condition "$f$ is $\gamma$-Hölder continuous" in Proposition 1 with "$f$ is **locally** $\gamma$-Hölder continuous everywhere". $\Diamond$

*Attempt of proof.* Since $M$ is separable, there exists a countable, dense subset $X$ of $M$. Then since $f$ is locally $\gamma$-Hölder continuous everywhere, there exist, for each point $x$ in $X$, two constants $\delta_{x}>0$ and $L_{x}\geq0$ so that for all $y\in M$ with $d_1(x,y)<\delta_x$, we have $d_2(f(x),f(y))\leq L_x\cdot\left(d_1(x,y)\right)^{\gamma}$. As $X$ is dense in $M$, we have
\begin{equation*}
    f(A)=\bigcup_{x\in X}f(B(x,\delta_x))
\end{equation*}
and so, by countable stability of $\mathcal{H}^{\infty}_{\alpha}$ and by Proposition 1, it is sufficient to show that $f\vert_{B(x,\delta_x)}$ is $\gamma$-Hölder continuous for all $x\in X$. Indeed, fix $x\in X$ and let $y,z$ be two points in $B(x,\delta_x)$. We see that
\begin{equation*}
    d_2(f(x),f(y))\leq L_{x}\cdot\left(d_1(x,y)\right)^{\gamma},\quad d_2(f(x),f(z))\leq L_{x}\cdot\left(d_1(x,z)\right)^{\gamma}
\end{equation*}
and, therefore, that
\begin{equation*}
    d_2(f(y),f(z))\leq L_{x}\cdot\left(d_1(x,y)\right)^{\gamma}+L_{x}\cdot\left(d_1(x,z)\right)^{\gamma}
\end{equation*}
How to go on? $\Diamond$

The definitions of Hölder continuity and local Hölder continuity I'm am referring to here are as below.

**Definition.** Let $(M,d_1)$ and $(N,d_2)$ be two metric spaces, $f:M\to N$ a function and $\gamma>0$ a constant. Then we say that $f$ is $\gamma$-Hölder continuous if there exists a constant $L\geq0$ so that, for all $x,y\in M$,
\begin{equation*}
    d_2(f(x),f(y))\leq L\cdot\left(d_1(x,y)\right)^{\gamma}
\end{equation*}
We then also say that $f$ has $\gamma$-Hölder constant $L$. $\Diamond$

**Definition.** Let $(M,d_1)$ and $(N,d_2)$ be two metric spaces, $f:M\to N$ a function, $\gamma>0$ a constant and $x\in M$ a point. Then we say that $f$ is locally $\gamma$-Hölder continuous at $x$ if there exist constants $\delta>0$ and $L\geq0$ so that, for all $y\in M$ with $d_1(x,y)<\delta$,
\begin{equation*}
    d_2(f(x),f(y))\leq L\cdot\left(d_1(x,y)\right)^{\gamma}
\end{equation*}
We then also say that $f$ has local $\gamma$-Hölder constant $L$ at $x$. $\Diamond$

**Definition.** Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space and $E$ a subset of $M$. For $\alpha\geq0$, we define the unlimited $\alpha$-Hausdorff content of $E$ by
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{H}_{\alpha}^{\infty}(E):=\inf\left\{\sum_n\left\vert F_n\right\vert^{\alpha}:\{F_n\}_n\text{ is a cover of }E\right\}
\end{equation*}
Further, we define the Hausdorff dimension of $E$ by
\begin{equation*}
\dim E:=\inf\{\alpha\in[0,\infty):\mathcal{H}_{\alpha}^{\infty}(E)=0\}
\end{equation*}
Note that both $\mathcal{H}_{\alpha}^{\infty}(E)$ and $\dim E$ are possibly infinite. $\Diamond$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the definition of local Holder continuity.  In general, we say that a property $P$ of metric spaces is satisfied locally in a metric space $M$, if every point in $M$ has an open neighborhood that satisfies $P$.

Specifically, The correct definition is:

**Definition.** Let $(M,d_1)$ and $(N,d_2)$ be two metric spaces, $f:M\to N$ a function, $\gamma>0$ a constant.  We say that $f$ is locally $\gamma$-Hölder continuous in $M$ if for every $x \in M$, there exist     $\delta, L>0$ so that, for all $y,z$ that satisfy $d_1(y,x)<\delta$ and $d_1(z,x)<\delta$,  we have
\begin{equation*}
    d_2(f(z),f(y))\leq L\cdot\left(d_1(z,y)\right)^{\gamma}
\end{equation*}
$\Diamond$
See https://second.wiki/wiki/lokale_hc3b6lderstetigkeit

In particular, if $f$ satisfies the definition above, then
$(*)$  The restriction of $f$ to any compact subset $K$ of $M$ is $\gamma$-Holder.

The  requirement $(*)$ is equivalent to the definition above if $M$ is locally compact.
The   requirement $(*)$ is the definition of local Holder continuity used in line 7 of
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition#H%C3%B6lder_spaces

Once one uses the above definition, the required inequality for Hausdorff dimension follows easily from the same inequality for globally Holder functions, separability of $M$ and countable stability of Hausdorff dimension.